# I am trying to encode an array into json but the loop is not working like it should

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

i want an array to be json_encode() but it is not working on this

```
foreach($sub_ids as $sub_id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sub_main WHERE sub_main_id = ".$sub_id;
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name = (String)$sub_id;
    $main["sub_heading".$sub_id]=$row1['sub_main_heading'];
    $main["sub_content".$sub_id]=$row1['sub_main_content'];
    $main["sub_images".$sub_id]=$row1['sub_main_images'];
    $main["sub_id".$sub_id]=$row1['sub_main_ids'];}
echo json_encode($main);
```

Sub_ids are 1 2 3

```
print_r($sub_ids);
```

shows

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

but its working when i remove the $sub_id, and that ends up overwriting the previous loop value.

basically json_encode is working for
$main['sub_heading'] but not for $main['sub_heading'.#sub_id]

it creates an array but does not encode it to json. please help.

Comment: print_r($sub_id) and show it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that `$sub_id` is an object.  Hence your conversion to a string in `$name=(String) $sub_id` .  Then your solution is change `$main["sub_heading".$sub_id]` to `$main["sub_heading".$name]`  and all should be golden

```
$main["sub_heading".$name]=$row1['sub_main_heading'];
$main["sub_content".$name]=$row1['sub_main_content'];
$main["sub_images".$name]=$row1['sub_main_images'];
$main["sub_id".$name]=$row1['sub_main_ids'];}
```

Comment: then I would move a print_r ($main) into the loop so you can monitor how the data is being populated and see why it's bombing out.  This could be a memory limit issue

Comment: it creates the array of the following but it does not encode it to json, how do i encode it to json, what do i change. it encode the array if i create an array like  **$main['this']=$row1['that']** but when i use **$main['this'.$sub_id]=$row1['that'.$sub_id]** in loop, it does not work

Comment: There are 2 answers, 1 you exceeded the memory limit. 2)The data is not in UTF-8 format (Like with certain special characters).  Those can bomb out a json_encode request.  That's why print_r is important, you can see if there is such a bad character